# how to use variables in "with" block in github actions

Tags: github-actions

I'm struggling a lot with github actions. This seems to work:

```
      - name: Tag & Push docker image
        run: |
          docker push myrepo/myapp:${GITHUB_SHA::8}
```

However, this does not:

```
      - name: create release
        uses: some-custom-action
        with:
          release_version: 1.0.0-${GITHUB_SHA::8}
```

nor this:

```
      - name: create release
        uses: some-custom-action
        with:
          release_version: "1.0.0-${{ env.GITHUB_SHA }}"
```

I'm completely new to github actions and more than a little surprised at the lacking documentation etc.

I simply need to pass a variable into the "with" parameters of a github action.

If anyone is able to help me figure out what I'm doing wrong, I'd be very grateful!

Comment: true. It wont make a difference tho. But thanks, cleaning it up.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When you use a `run` context, you're invoking a shell.  (For macOS and Linux hosts, this is `/bin/bash`.)  So for this step:

```
- name: Tag & Push docker image
  run: |
    docker push myrepo/myapp:${GITHUB_SHA::8}
```

you're using a shell and `${GITHUB_SHA::8}` will be passed to it literally.  The shell will then parse that and interpolate it with its normal parsing rules.

However, when you specify an *action* to run, instead of a script to execute, you're just invoking a different program.  There's no shell, so there's nothing that will parse `${GITHUB_SHA::8}`.

You can use `${{ ... }}` to reference things [in the contexts that are available](https://help.github.com/en/actions/reference/context-and-expression-syntax-for-github-actions).  For example, there's an `env` context that is open for you to set key/value pairs and re-use them.  (But the `env` context is **not part of a `bash` shell**, so there's no `${{ env.PWD }}` for instance.)

There *is* a mapping, however, between [the `github` context](https://help.github.com/en/actions/reference/context-and-expression-syntax-for-github-actions#github-context) and [environment variables that are set when you *do* run a shell](https://help.github.com/en/actions/configuring-and-managing-workflows/using-environment-variables).  The `${{ github.sha }}` context variable will be set in your shell as the `$GITHUB_SHA` environment variable.

So in your example, this should work:

```
- name: create release
  uses: some-custom-action
  with:
    release_version: "1.0.0-${{ github.sha }}"
```

Comment: My built `apk` output has a dynamic name which uses the current branch and the commit hash which I can interrogate by `git branch --show-current` and `git rev-parse --short HEAD` respectively. How can I capture these as variables so that `actions/upload-artifact@v1` can upload the built `apk`?